# Kris Kowal's design promises article

Tags: javascript, promise

I am reading a Kris Kowal's [design article](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/tree/v1/design) about promises.
I have a question regarding to a **blah** function.
Why this function in some cases will throw an exception?
How to reproduce this exceptional case?

> ## Safety and Invariants

```
 var blah = function () {
     var result = foob().then(function () {
         return barf();
     });
     var barf = function () {
         return 10;
     };
     return result; };
```

> This function will either throw an exception or return a promise that
>   will quickly be fulfilled with the value of 10.  It depends on whether
>   foob() resolves in the same turn of the event loop (issuing its
>   callback on the same stack immediately) or in a future turn.  If the
>   callback is delayed to a future turn, it will allways succeed.

Comment: the quote at the bottom of your own question explain it pretty explicitly. *It depends on whether foob() resolves in the same turn of the event loop (issuing its callback on the same stack immediately) or in a future turn. If the callback is delayed to a future turn, it will always succeed.*

Comment: @JarrodRoberson yes, but OP did not understand _why_ that is the case - that is, why it'll throw an exception.

Comment: this also has nothing to do with promises and is a duplicate of many other questions about the exact same thing

Comment: @JarrodRoberson "This document is intended to explain how promises work..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just JavaScript, since `barf` is defined *after* the `then` callback is registered - if the then callback is called synchronously - it will not be defined yet and it'll be the same as doing:

```
(undefined)();
```

Which is an error. Illustrating:

```
// this code works
setTimeout(function(){
    foo("HI");
});
var foo = alert;

// this code throws
(function(){
    foo("Hi");
})();
var foo = alert;
```

Promise libraries make sure that callbacks are always called when the engine is executing platform code - so with promises this is not a problem if they're Promises/A(+) compliant. jQuery's promises for instance will fail here depending on whether or not `foob` was resolved in jQuery 1 and 2 but not 3 (they fixed it).

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you.
It depends on how foob will be implemented.
//no exception
var foob = function() {
    var d = defer();
    setTimeout(function(){d.resolve()}, 1);
    return d.promise;
    return ref(1);
};

//exception
var foob = function() {
    return ref(1);
};